# Tournaments for the No-Forced-Jumps Checkers?

Tags: checkers

Are there any tournaments for the No Forced Jump version of the Checkers?

I grew up only playing the No Forced Jumps variant of Checkers. I see now that there are tournaments for the Forced Jumps version, and I see how that appears to be the more respected variant of the game generally.  Are there any organized groups that hold to this variant?

Answer (score 6):

As per Sultan Ratrout's *"[A Guide to Checkers Families and Rules](http://www.fmjd.org/downloads/variants/Checkers_families_and_rules_28-9-2018.pdf)"* there aren't any current officiated rules that do not include mandatory capture of one form or another.

While many people play without mandatory capture in casual settings it is strictly speaking a **house rule**, and so most likely *will not* be found in any serious tournament setting.

Comment: I would assume this is to prevent forced stalemates.

Comment: anecdotal evidence suggests it does reduce draws, but it's not 100% effective, as perfect play always results in a draw.